# non v-tec swap to a v-tec

Tags: honda, civic, electronic-control-module, vtec

ive got a 98 civic dx  engine is a D16y7 non v-tec  I have swapped engines to a v-tec D16Z6. im having problems with the ecu it does not work on a v-tec motor. it does start the car but no v-tec ive got access to a P28 A02 ecu that came out of a 94 civic ex with a manual transmission. my 98 by the way is an automatic transmission  will this work in my 98 civic and have everything working correctly  such as the v-tec and shifting correctly as well I will also say that it is difficult to find good used ecu's in my neighborhood so if there is a way to make this work correctly  please help me out with this and clue me in on how to do this .           Clueless in Yelm

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you are using the non-VTEC ECU, I'm not sure why you'd think it would work with the new motor? There's electronic controls involved which tells the VTEC to engage. My knowledge of what you can and cannot do with the VTEC stuff on the Honda engines is limited, so leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Also, more than likely the 94 ECU won't work for you because it will be OBDI and your car will be OBDII (regardless of VTEC capability).

Comment: Put as a comment as comments were made...The ecu that you use must match the engine and you will probably need the under-bonnet harness as well as there may be some differences there as well.

Once it is all connected, you may find that you will need to "code" or "program" the ecu to the engine and to do this you will need access to "garage" level equipment: a cheap code reader will not suffice.